# set password local admin account from gpo grey out

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I'm trying to enable and password set to local administrator account to all my domain computers from domain controller's gpo. But I can't set the password for local admin. It is grey out.

[image: Password grey out]

Comment: That functionality is no longer available - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2962486/ms14-025-vulnerability-in-group-policy-preferences-could-allow-elevati